# Can we set backgroundImage for Section in UITableview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

[image]Can we set Background image for `UITableView` Section like `UITableViewCell` `backGroundView`. As per my research Its not possible & we need to customize the row like section of it.
Cane we able to get better solution apart from this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857241/set-backgroundimage-to-uitableview-section-viewforheaderinsection

Comment: I need for entire section, not for headerview of Section.

Comment: @Madhu Did you try like this? Crop you single image into several and add as a section header background and each cell background respectively.. I think it will look like what you need..

Comment: @R.A Perfect!!! Its looks like it will work as we expected. But small issue occur-res using this i guess, while scrolling table it will fix the section header until that section rows completed. then it looks odd to visible. I think you got my point...

Comment: Ya sure.. I know that before itself. But i thought something is better than nothing.. So gave you that solution.. will let you know if i got better idea. Actually I have a doubt. How it should look like, when you scroll the tableview?? If you have a pattern then that is easy way to show as colorWithPatterImage: method in all the cell backgrounds and header too. If you have a Image(not pattern), then it may create a problem when the number of cells are increasing or decreasing sometimes or it may not compact with the image you providing.

Comment: @R.A Thanks for your reply. Attached the screen shot of it. Please check it.

Comment: its looking good.. Its just a color or pattern..thats easy then.. what is the issue in it..??

Comment: @R.A Its an easy. But provided sample here for reference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24803/discussion-between-r-a-and-madhu)

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone are still interrested, there is actually a pretty straigt forward solution to this. UITableView will tell you the frames of each of your sections using the selector rectForSection:

Adding a backgroud image to each section would then look something like this (Somewhere in the view controller):

```
  for(int i = 0;i < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView]; i++) {
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0) ]; //In this example the image is stretchable
        UIView *borderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        CGRect section_rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:i];
        borderView.frame = section_rect;
        [self.tableView addSubview:borderView];
    }
```

Just remember that if you reload the data in the tableview you would have to redo this as well.

Comment: Have been developing for so many years, but didn't know that method ever existed :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am doing this by following way, I think it work for you also,....

```
        -(void)addBackgroundViewForSectionIndex:(int)tagIndex {

           for (UIView * subview in tableView.subviews) {
             if(subview.tag == tagIndex)
               [subview removeFromSuperview];
           }

          CGRect sectionFrame = [tableView rectForSection:tagIndex];
          UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:sectionFrame];
          newView.tag = tagIndex;
          [newView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.PNG"]];
          [tableView addSubview:newView];
          [tableView sendSubviewToBack:newView];

        }

      // Customize the appearance of table view cells.

       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:      (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          if (cell == nil) {
                  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                           }

                 cell.textLabel.text = [collection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


             [self addBackgroundViewForSectionIndex:indexPath.section];

                return cell;
             }
```

Let me know if any issue,...:)

Comment: I also add this:

I also did this:

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.bringSubviewToFront(cell)
}`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 bare-bones implementation of Jesper's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239067/10830091).

```
for sectionIndex in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
    let backgroundView = UIView() // replace UIView with anything else you want, whether it was UIImage, nibView, etc...
    backgroundView.frame = tableView.rect(forSection: sectionIndex)
    tableView.addSubview(backgroundView)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible using `UITableView` as it was intended. Section headers, as others have suggested, won't work because they'll only be visible while the header is visible. As soon as it disappears while scrolling up, the background image would disappear.

Your two options are:

- Add `UIImageView` instances directly as subviews to the table view. Not fun, as you'll have to size and position them manually, which is kind of hard to do.
- Use `UICollectionView`, which supports decoration views (exactly what you're looking for).

The `UICollectionView` method is probably better, but to be honest, either option would require a lot of work.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the Background for Section of TableView.

Have a look at delegate method as below:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIImageView *bgImgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,tableView.bounds.size.width,40.0)] autorelease];
    bgImgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];

    return bgImgView;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: Its works for Section Header view, But I need to entire section.

Comment: I am not getting you. You means, there is only one Header or anything else. Please elaborate more on this. So that, I can better help you. Screenshot will be appreciated.

Comment: @Rushi: y co-ordinate (0.0) means, it will starts from starting of Header. Means it will take y co-ordinate of Header by it's own.

Comment: @Rushi: it's header image view height. And you need to implement "heightForHeader" method and need to set it's height "40.0" or according to your need.

Comment: @NishantB : according to your need correct. So why you choose it to be 40.0 pixels??

Answer (score -1):

```
table= [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7,0, 307, 124) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

[table  setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tablebg_pt12.png"]];

imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 307, 124);

imageView.image= [UIImage  imageNamed:@"tablebg_pt12.png" ];


    table.backgroundView = imageView;
    [imageView release];


    table.delegate = self;
    table.dataSource = self;

    // table.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [viewTable addSubview:table];
```

Comment: you can create table manually add image in background of table

Comment: Please don't post section Header View & background images logic her.e i Know for BackgroundImage and Section header view.